# Local database in Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight application from SQL Server

Tags: c#, sqlite, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

I have an SQL Server database on my local computer. I want to copy that database schema (SQL Server) to my local database in Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight application (SQLite). So I want to have exactly the same database on my phone. How can I create it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a solution. [Convert SQL Server DB to SQLite DB](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26932/Convert-SQL-Server-DB-to-SQLite-DB).